# Should I accept a good but incomplete answer?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

My question [Which spheres are fiber bundles?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189535/which-spheres-are-fiber-bundles) has one very nice response, but the response does not completely answer the question.

I'd like to reward the response, but on the other hand I'd like to leave the discussion open in case we can get more information.  So far I just upvoted the response and followed up in the comments.

Are there more detailed guidelines here?

Comment: As the person who stands to get reputation out of this, let me just say that I'm really not picky either way about whether or not you accept.  I'm just sorry I'm not knowledgeable enough to know the full answer ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Not a guideline, but just to throw out an option:

If you feel that an answer should *not* be accepted but *should be* awarded with more than an up vote, one possibility is to [use the bounty system](https://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties).

Answer (score 4):

The questions for which an answer has been accepted are clearly marked with green background; one does not need to open a question to see that it has an accepted answer. My interpretation of the green background is "the issue has been resolved". Consequently, I am much less likely to open a question which already has an accepted answer.

So, I think it is reasonable to not accept an answer until either the question is completely settled or you give up the hope of finding more.

Incidentally, if the lack of accepted answer results in more users reading the question (which I think is the case), the non-accepted answer may well earn additional upvotes in the long run, compensating for the lack of +15.

Comment: It is often worthwhile to peruse questions with accepted answers since one may be able to give much better answers. This is especially true for questions by new users, who often make the mistake of accepting answers too quickly (often the first answer posted). Further, the questioner may not have the knowledge to judge whether or not better answers are possible.

Comment: @Bill I do not disagree, but having only finite amount of time, I take obviously unanswered questions as a higher priority... and rarely ever get to the items of lower priority.

Answer (score 3):

You should accept what *you* find acceptable. That may mean to you useful, or informative, or a great effort... all sort of things.

I would only suggest not accepting an answer which is not helpful for you. Even if an answer looks cool and seems to be the canonically perfect way of answering your question, if you *personally* cannot make much of it then do not accept it.